# Provide arguments in auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, command-line-arguments, auto-py-to-exe

I am using Auto-py-to-exe to create an executable for my python script. Problem is, my python script takes in an argument called '--output-path' which is required. If I run my code in a command prompt I would say something like,

```
python fetch_sbom_packages.py --output-path C:\Users\TEMP\repo\OutputFolder
```

Now here is Auto-py-to-exe I see a section called Settings. Under that I see Manually Argument Input. What do I specify for the argument here?

[image: arguments]

Here is the main method in my script. (See the required=True for --output-path)

```
async def main(*args):

    try:
        print('arguments specified',sys.argv)
        # Set up the command line parser.
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            prog = 'sbom',
            description = 'Scan the Vision repositories for components used in the SBOM.',
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument('--ssh-prefix',
            default='git@github.com:',
            dest='ssh_prefix',
            help='ssh prefix (default: "git@github.com:")',
            metavar='PREFIX',
            type=str)
        parser.add_argument('--output-path',
            dest='output_path',
            required=True,
            help='name of the output path',
            metavar='OUTPUTPATH',
            type=Path)
        
        # Parse the command line. This function prints
        # an error and exits the program when there is
        # a malformed command line.
        args = parser.parse_args()
        
        # Load the configuration.
        config = Configuration()
        settings_file = config.etc_path / 'sbom.json'
        with settings_file.open() as f:
            j = json.load(f)
            repositories = j['repositories']
            rules = j['rules']
            snapshots = j['snapshots']
        
        # Find every repository that is needed by at
        # least one snapshot.
        repositories_to_fetch = set()
        for name in repositories:
        
            # Don't fetch the repository when
            # there are no patterns defined.
            patterns = repositories[name]['patterns']
            if not patterns: continue
        
            # Otherwise, fetch the repository when there is
            # at least one snapshot with a non-null commit.
           
            if any(snapshot[name] for snapshot in snapshots.values() if snapshot):
                 repositories_to_fetch.add(name)
        
        # Always fetch the GitHub advisiory repository.
        repositories_to_fetch.add('advisory-database')
        
        # Fetch the repositories.
        for name in sorted(repositories_to_fetch, key=lambda a: a.casefold()):
            if name == 'advisory-database':
               continue
            local_path = config.repo_cache_path / name
            #remote_path = args.ssh_prefix + 'https://github.com/BeclsAutomation/Echo65XPlus' #repositories[name]['url']
            remote_path='https://github.com/BeclsAutomation/Echo65XPlus'
            fetch_git_repository(local_path, remote_path)
        
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        
            # The package cache is used to minimize queries to the
            # package servers. It can be shared across snapshots.
            package_cache = PackageCache(session)
            versioned_package_cache = VersionedPackageCache(session)
        
            # Fetch the packages for each snapshot. We don't need the beaver and alligator. We need only dev (Update sbom.json)
            for snapshot_name, snapshot in snapshots.items():
                artifact_path = args.output_path / snapshot_name
                await fetch_packages(session, package_cache, versioned_package_cache,config.repo_cache_path, artifact_path, repositories, snapshot, rules)
        
    except:
        print("Please see SBOM_help_text.py to see the full detailed usage")
```